# Ошибка сегментации (C++ в ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: c++, g++, segmentation-fault

Программа выдаёт ошибку сегментации при обращении к последнему элементу двумерного массива в цикле его обработки. Более того, она имеет странные значения x и y в начале(но это вопрос второстепенный). Странно так же и то, что я продумал вариант выхода за границы массива, но ошибка происходит при обращении к последнему элементу. Есть подозрение на ошибку в реализации механики цикла for, но это как-то слишком странно и даже не верится...
В чём может быть ошибка? Код (да, ошибку искал cout'ами, не бейте)
Забавен тот факт, что из for в нужный момент программа не производит выход. Не делать же железобетонную проверку переменных - итераторов x и y на их значения...
Из-за чего возникает сегфолт?

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    const int X = 10;
    const int Y = 10;
    int field[X][Y];
    int n = 0; //итератор для перечисления одномерных массивов
    int x, y, x_sec = 0;
    //x_iterator = X - 1;
    //y_iterator = Y - 1;
    int point_x[10],
        point_y[10]; //массивы в которые определяются координаты точек.

    for (x = 0; x < X; x++)
    {
        for (y = 0; y < Y; y++)
        {
            field[x][y] = rand() % 2;
            cout << setw(6) << left << field[x][y];
        }

        cout << endl;
    }

    cout << x << " " << y << " " << endl;

    for (x = 0; x < X; //изначально было x<=X И y<=Y соответственно, что давало явный вылет. Ситуация от смены условий на строгие не поменялась.
            x++) // цикл обработки. тут возникает ошибка при условии что x = 10
    {
        cout << "debug point 1" << endl;

        for (y = 0; y < Y; y++) //и y = 10
        {
            cout << "x = " << x << " y = " << y << endl;
            cout << "debug point 2" << endl;

            if (field[x][y] >
                    0) //захват первой точки. Если она есть, то в point_x, point_y [n] пишутся координаты ненулевого элемента
            {
                cout << "адрес массива - " << x << " " << y << endl;
                cout << "debug point 3" << endl;
                point_x[n] = x;
                point_x[n] = y;
                n++;
                cout <<  "N = " << n << " point x = " << point_x[n] << " point y =" <<
                     point_y[n] <<  endl;
                cout << "debug point 4" << endl;

                for (x_sec = x; x_sec < X - 1; x_sec++)
                {
                    cout << "адрес подмассива(s_sec) " << x_sec << " " << y << endl;
                    cout << "debug point 5" << endl;

                    if (field[x_sec][y] > 0)
                    {
                        cout << "debug point 6" << endl;
                        point_x[n] = x_sec;
                        point_y[n] = y;
                        n++;
                        cout << "x_sec = " << x_sec << " y = " << y << endl;
                        cout << "debug point 7 | N = " << n << " point x = " << point_x[n] <<
                             " point y =" << point_y[n] <<  endl;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "debug point 8" << endl;
                n = 0;
                point_x[n] = 0;
                point_y[n] = 0;
                cout << "debug point 9 " << x << " " << y << endl;
            }

            cout << "x = " << x << " y = " << y << endl;
            cin.get();
        }
    }

    cout << point_x[0] << " " << point_y[0];
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Внесу свою лепту. Посмотрите внимательно на этот участок кода:

```
        point_x[n] = x;
        point_x[n] = y;
        n++;
        cout <<  "N = " << n << " point x = " << point_x[n] << " point y =" <<
             point_y[n] <<  endl;
```

Во-первых, полагаю, что во второй строке вы хотели написать `point_y[n] = y`, но закрался коварный copy-paste. Получилось, что вы дважды переписываете один и тот же участок памяти.

Во-вторых, выражение `n++` **инкрементирует** значение индекса `n`, а значит в следующей строке происходит обращение уже к следующему элементу массива. На последней итерации цикла это приводит к выходу за пределы массива. Правильно было бы написать так:

```
int prev = n++;
cout << "N = " << prev << " point x = " << point_x[prev] << " point y =" <<
         point_y[prev] << endl;
```

Заметьте, таких проблемных участков в вашем коде несколько.

Comment: P.S. В логике работы кода не разбирался. Указал только очевидные ошибки.

Comment: Задание: опередлить из спрея точек квадраты
Логика работы такова, что в координатной сетке(двумерный массив) ищутся точки(единицы) если в строке найдена первая точка, то в массивы point_x и point_y [n-ые] запоминаются её координаты. Далее в той же строке ищется вторая единицы и запоминаются её координаты. 
Из не написанного там по смыслу надо было высчитать расстояние от первой до второй точки и прибавить это расстояние к y и проверить, есть ли там единицы или нет. Если есть, то это квадрат.

Comment: Более того, тут не коварный копипаст, а банальная рассеянность, тот кусок я писал ручками. Потом уже когда писал сюда вопрос, я его заметил и поправил.

Answer (score 2):

У вас все массивы размера `10`, т.е. с индексами от `0` до `9`. А вот в этих циклах вдруг

```
for (x = 0; x <= X; x++)
    for (y = 0; y <= Y; y++)
```

идет доступ по индексам `10` из-за нестрогого сравнения `<=`. Это явный вылет за пределы массива.

При этом в цикле ввода у вас все сделано правильно (сравнения в условиях циклов строгие), а здесь вдруг почему-то стало `x <= X` и `y <= Y`. Почему?

Comment: цимес в том, что до этого было как надо.

Comment: хм... переделал так как надо. почему-то заработало О_о

Comment: Ан нет! Не работает! Даже с изменением условия итераторов на x<X и y<Y(пользуюсь Geany, он сначала не хотел пересобирать исполняемый файл) Теперь когда x и y = 9(что отображено в последнем cout в цикле обработки) происходит вылет

Comment: @MarKo: Ну ошибка с циклами - налицо. А дальше уже смотрите... У вас есть еще один замечательный потенциал для вылета за пределы массива - массивы `point_x` и `point_y`. Что у вас успешно и происходит, напр. в "debug point 6"-"debug point 7" .

Comment: а там-то в чём дело? Там же всего 2 одномерных массива которые связаны номером n который определяет номер захваченной точки. Согласен с тем, что он во-первых отрезан лишнего, что не есть хорошо. А потом я в point_x переприсваиваю значение y что есть плохо!

Comment: Ну так ваш номер `n` в военное время запросто достигает "астрономических" величин, которые больше 10. Это хорошо видно в вашей же отладочной печати для "debug point 7". Вы сами-то собственную отладочную печать читать пробовали? А уж почему это происходит, и должно ли это происходить - это уже надо спрашивать у вас.

Comment: Происходить этого не должно. Увидел. Сейчас посмотрю в чём юмор там. И можешь ещё объяснить почему у меня y убегает в дебаге куда-то в сторону моря? (debug point 7 point y) значения иногда вылетают за пределы допустимого. Или это из-за N ?

Comment: Ошибка сегментации действительно происходила из-за N. Ошибка была в том, что Else блок должен стоять у вложенного условия, а не у первого. Из-за чего происходит нарушение смысла алгоритма. 
задание такое: найти точки образующие квадраты и найти квадрат с максимальным количеством точек принадлежащих его площади.
А смысл таков, что:
бежим по массиву, ищем первую точку и пишем её координаты в отдельный массив
   если найдена, то ищем вторую и тоже пишем, в противном случае обнуляем массивы для записи координат point_x и point_y